# @OneToOne Jpa with Database view receiving error message 'referenced relation is not a table'

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I've a hibernate project working fine (almost). But one relationship with database view isn't working. Somebody could help me ?

Hibernate 5.2
Postgresql 9
Maven
Eclipse
Apache Tomcat 9

**My View**

```
@Entity
@Immutable
public class vclientesgds implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "c_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private Long c_id;

@Column
private Long store_id;

@Column
private String cnpj;

@Column
private String company_name;
...
```

My Class

```
@Entity
public class EmailGds implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public EmailGds() {
    System.out.println("E-mails Google Data Studio");
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "emails_gds_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "emails_gds_seq", sequenceName = "emailsgds_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@Column
private Long id;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "c_id", nullable = false)
private vclientesgds c_id;
...
```

When I start the project, I receive the message error:

```
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@2b843f9b] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
```

Hibernate:

```
alter table if exists napp_front.EmailGds 
   add constraint FKo824l96t9lt54slsms879qku6 
   foreign key (c_id) 
   references napp_front.vclientesgds
ago 06, 2021 6:03:55 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl         handleException
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via     JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
...

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: referenced relation "vclientesgds" is not a table
at     org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2285)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:323)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:481)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:401)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:322)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:308)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:284)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:279)
at     org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetTo    Database.java:54)
... 53 more
```

I've used @SubSelect too, but without sucess

Comment: one small comment here, better use the standard java naming convention for variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable the generation of the foreign key:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "c_id", 
foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "none", 
value = ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT,
nullable = false))
```